Organic compound nomenclature



As I learn nomenclature, I was told that -OH has higher priority than alkene. However, the last compound says otherwise. What is the key here?

What would be the last compound's name if the priorities worked the way you initially thought?

I figured it out. I suppose it is because -OH group is numbered 4 regardless of how we start the chain. While starting from the right leaves alkene at 5th position, from the left leaves alkene at 2th position. I guess thats the point

Exactly.$\mathstrut$

You should try to change the title of the question. As it stands, it is too generic.

The priority order you have mentioned is used to determine the secondary suffix. Secondary suffix indicates the functional group present in the molecule. It is added after the primary suffix (which identifies single/double/triple bonds) . Depending on the number of occurrences of the same functional group in a compound, the words like di, tri, tetra etc., are prefixed to the secondary suffix. The -ol used at the end of the names of all the three compounds instead of -ene (for double bonds) show that alcohol has a 'higher priority', i.e. is the primary functional group in the compounds. After the primary functional group is identified and the parent chain is selected, the positions have to be numbered.
The rules suggest that the numbering should start from the end from where the functional group closest to that end gets a lower locant. 
Let us understand using the example of the first compound. By following both blue or red way of numbering, the functional group closest to the respective end gets the locant 2. This is a 'tie' so we move on to the next functional group. If we use the red locants we get the number 3 where as we get 4 when we use blue locants. As we have to prefer lower locants, we use start numbering from the right hence the name. 

This hopefully helps you understand that we start numbering from the left in the third compound as the first locant in lowest in that case.
